# SafeFileHandle.Close throws an exception but the handle is valid and works

Tags: c#, wpf, handle

I'm having a problem with custom cursors in a WPF application. I use the following code to create the `Cursor` objects:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect(ref IconInfo icon);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);

private static Cursor CreateCursor(string cursorName, System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, 
    int xHotspot, int yHotspot, out SafeFileHandle handle)
{
    IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
    GetIconInfo(bmp.GetHicon(), ref tmp);
    tmp.xHotspot = xHotspot;
    tmp.yHotspot = yHotspot;
    tmp.fIcon = false;

    IntPtr ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
    handle = new SafeFileHandle(ptr, true);

    if (handle.IsClosed)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Cursor cur = CursorInteropHelper.Create(handle);

    return cur;
}
```

When I close my application and GC starts picking up the trash, it throws an exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=mscorlib
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CloseHandle(IntPtr handle)
       at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.ReleaseHandle()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()
       at System.Windows.Input.Cursor.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

I did some further investigation by placing a breakpoint on `if (handle.IsClosed)` and using the immediate window to call `handle.Close()`. Some of the `SafeFileHandle`'s close just fine, others throw the same exception — immediately after the handle was created.

And just to make things fun, the handles themselves work just fine. `IsInvalid` is false, `IsClosed` is false, and the cursors appear. It's just that some of the handles can never be closed.

As I never intend to close the handles manually, and they will only be closed during finalization of the `Cursor` objects when the application closes, I might be able to just ignore them. I haven't tried a Release build outside VS2010 and I don't know if that will cause a crash dialog to appear. But even if I can ignore them, it's still messy.

So basically I'm looking for any info on what might be going wrong here, where to look to try and debug this... everything seems to be in native code or GC and I can't debug any of it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're wrapping the `HICON` returned from `CreateIconIndirect` in a `SafeFileHandle` which, on releasing, calls `CloseHandle` on the `HICON` instead of the needed `DestroyIcon`. Don't wrap `HICON` in `SafeFileHandle` but instead in an own, specialized `SafeHandle`:

```
class SafeIconHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DestroyIcon(
        [In] IntPtr hIcon);

    private SafeIconHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    public SafeIconHandle(IntPtr hIcon)
        : base(true)
    {
        this.SetHandle(hIcon);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return DestroyIcon(this.handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to WPF, never done WinForms, and this is my first time having to deal with native code. And thanks for removing your comment and making this an answer. :)

Comment: @RyanP You're welcome. Such things are easy to miss, especially if everything seems working at the first look.

Comment: Thats the awesome thing , i was also facing the same issue, i got it fixed by using the this custom SafeIconHandle class